# Websphere Portal 8.5, portlets is changing JSESSIONID

Tags: websphere-8, websphere-portal, jsessionid

I deployd release with some script portlets applications on more managed pages to production as is described here:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHRKX_8.5.0/mp/deploy/dep_deploy.dita?lang=en

Portlets have security restrictions to authentificated users. After I first time logged in its all OK. However when I try to click on another page on that portal I'm redirected to login page again.

I investigated it in web browser console. There were changing JSESSIONID in cookie every GET method:

```
...sessionCode=-776125765; JSESSIONID=0000f7VRxv0SelqdHKq_cdSkfwr:-1;...
...sessionCode=-776125765; JSESSIONID=0000CgNGvCB89PS5pam1KA4q1jM:-1;...
...sessionCode=-776125765; JSESSIONID=0000LzkNhV2ycEx9irw8ueRJeV6:-1;...
```

But in source portal it stay the same:

```
...sessionCode=-776125765; JSESSIONID=0000S9uf4WFCR1-HbNKvK2oRwVp:-1;...
...sessionCode=-776125765; JSESSIONID=0000S9uf4WFCR1-HbNKvK2oRwVp:-1;...
...sessionCode=-776125765; JSESSIONID=0000S9uf4WFCR1-HbNKvK2oRwVp:-1;...
```

Have someone some ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any embedded links to other sites/applications in the same domain ?

May be that application is changing the JSESSIONID cookie - causing the portal app to invalidate.

Usually if we have multiple servers running on the same system or domain - we change the name of the JSESSIONID.